# Vim Plug no se reconoce en windows 10

Tags: windows10, powershell, vim

tengo un problema con vim y el gestor de paquetes Vim Plug.

Instale Vim para windows, usando powershell y windows terminal. Me cree el archivo `_vimrc` donde tengo mi configuracion, la cual funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando deseo agregar `vim plug`, me genera un error

```
edgargc026@LAPTOP-AGB50S2O ❯ vim C:\Users\edgargc026\_vimrc                                                             
Error detected while processing /c/Users/edgargc026/_vimrc:                                                             
line   41:                                                                                                              
E117: Unknown function: plug#begin                                                                                      line   43:                                                                                                              
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'                                                             
line   44:                                                                                                              
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'https://github.com/junegunn/vim-github-dashboard.git'                                
line   46:                                                                                                              
E117: Unknown function: plug#end                                                                                        
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Si abro la configuracion tengo lo siguiente:

```
call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/plugged')  

Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
Plug 'https://github.com/junegunn/vim-github-dashboard.git'

call plug#end()
```

En la documentación oficial de Plug, me recomiendan esa ruta, sin embargo me genera el mismo error.

Ya intente verificar con `:scriptnames` y me arroja esto:

```
:script
scriptencoding  scriptnames
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim81/defaults.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim
  9: ~/_vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/gzip.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/logiPat.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/manpager.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/spellfile.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tohtml.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim81/scripts.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/vim.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent/vim.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/vim.vim
```

Ya no tengo idea de que otra cosa puede ser ¿Alguien le ha sucedido lo mismo al intentar instalar vim plug en windows?